# Use Blend QML Type with differently sized images

Tags: qt, qml, blending

The example listed in the documentation for QML's [Blend Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-blend.html) show how to blend two images together. How can one achieve the same effect when working with images that are differently sized?

I have a background image with FHD resolution and smaller components on top that need to be blended into it. However, using the approach shown in the documentation shrinks the background to the same size as the component.

Here's the code I'm working with, adapted from the example in the above link.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Image {
        id: backgroundImg
        source: "path/to/backgroundImg"
        
        // Set true because I want the background image
        // and blended component to both show up.
        visible: true
    }

    Image {
        id: component1
        source: "path/to/component1"
        visible: false
    }

    Blend {
        anchors.fill: component1
        source: backgroundImg
        foregroundSource: component1
        mode: "color"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `Item` that is as big as the background image and place the foreground image inside of it. Use the `Item` as the `foregroundSource`.

This way you don't need the background image to be visible, because the edges fully expose the background image.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Image {
        id: background
        source: "https://picsum.photos/id/485/640/480"
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: foreground
        anchors.fill: background
        visible: false

        Image {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            source: "https://picsum.photos/id/486/260/320"
        }
    }

    Blend {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: background
        foregroundSource: foreground
        mode: "lighten"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I did think of that, but the reason I would like to avoid it is that some of my components are exactly the same but placed at different locations. Doing it this way means all of them would need to be customized and I won't be able to reuse the same asset in rows etc.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Looking at the source of the `Blend` effect the shader is using `texture2D(backgroundSource, qt_TexCoord0)` on both sources (foreground and background). Using the same texture coordinate to request a pixel from different sized textures will result in one being stretched. You could write a custom version of `Blend` using `ShaderEffect` to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ShaderEffectSource`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html) to extract a part of an item.

In your case (shamelessly copied from @iam_peter's answer):

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Image {
        id: background
        visible: true
        source: "https://picsum.photos/id/485/640/480"
    }

    Image {
        id: foreground
        visible: false
        anchors.centerIn: background
        source: "https://picsum.photos/id/486/260/320"
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: shaderEffectSource
        visible: false
        sourceItem: background
        sourceRect: background.mapFromItem(foreground,
                                           0, 0, foreground.width, foreground.height)
        onSourceRectChanged: print(sourceRect, foreground.x, foreground.width)
    }

    Blend {
        id: blend
        anchors.fill: foreground
        source: shaderEffectSource
        foregroundSource: foreground
        mode: "lighten"
    }
}
```